# Python code if the input is not hat the user needs to do an input again?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginer in python and I have a homework and I am stuck a little. 
The user needs to make an input and if the input is not string, the user needs to make another input for so long until the input is string.
First I need to make an input and then check what kind of input it was but then I dont know how to make it possible for the user to make another input. 
Thank you in front!

The code I started with:

```
name = input ("Imput the name: ")
if name != str:
    print ("The input name needs to be string!")
```

Comment: you can't be using both `python3.x` _and_ `python2.7`. which is it?

Comment: Please show an example of your code progression. We need to determine what you have attempted to help you along without just giving you the code.

Comment: name = input ("Imput the name: ")
if name != str:
    print ("The input name needs to be string!")

Comment: @Matic1295 by string you mean input should contain alphabetic characters?

Comment: Yes. And then I have a same example for integers. If a input is not a number the user needs to make another input until the input is number.

Answer (score 3):

when data (input) is alphabetic characters

```
data = input()
val = True
while val:
    if data.isalpha():
        print('given input is correct string')
        val = False
    data = input()
```

when data (input) is an integer value

```
data = input()
val = True
while val:
    if data.isdigit():
        print('given input is correct numbers')
        val = False
    data = input()
```